# Error while browsing angular 8 app which is deployed in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Please let me know why i am seeing below error when browsing angular app( version 8), my default app runs on localhost:4200 but i get error when i try to browse in azure, i am using azure app service extension in visual code and deploying through that and i dint see any error while deploying, i read some one mentioning adding port in config would resolve the issue, but it didn't, let me know what i am missing here.

Config file with port number

[image]

error in azure log stream

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure App service only supports port 80/443. You can do `app.listen(process.env.PORT);` in your code. I had a similar issue when hosting node app. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821043/how-to-debug-nodejs-app-on-azure-app-service-getting-http-status-code-500).

Comment: deployment using windows advanced app help, appreciate your help
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs#deploy-zip-file

Answer (score 1):

Build the web application before deploying with the `ng build*` command. This command will create the `dist/project-sample` directory containing a transpiled, minified, ready-to-deploy version of your application.

Deploying to an Azure Web App is as simple as right-clicking on the web app in the Azure App Service extension and selecting the “Deploy to Web App” option. The extension will make a suggestion on what to deploy but use the Browse option to **select the `dist/project-sample` folder instead**.

Also the default version of Node on the Azure Web App is not the version that you want to use. Luckily, the version of node can be changed with the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` with value `10.16.0`. environment variable. Navigate to the Application settings section of the Application settings page for your Azure Web App.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/deploy-an-angular-app-from-visual-studio-code-to-a-1). BTW, check your web.config with this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59757914/deploy-simple-angular-8-app-to-azure-with-visual-studio-code).

Comment: Thanks for the reply i did all of those but still get the above message, and the web app is listening to localhost:4200

Comment: The localhost port is different with azure http port, so you do not need to confuse.